# joining tables but not showing rows where clause is met

Tags: mysql, join, between

I am joining tables in mysql but I have one table that holds dates as so:

```
table: cutoff

      date       roomid  
---------------------------  
    2012-11-03     25
    2012-11-04     25
    2012-11-05     25
    2012-11-06     25
```

And here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT t.RoomId, t.USD, t.MXN, i.Image, a.RoomName, a.RoomDesc, cu.date FROM Tarifas AS t 
INNER JOIN Images AS i ON i.RoomId = t.RoomId
INNER JOIN Availability AS a ON a.RoomId = t.RoomId 
INNER JOIN cutoff AS cu ON cu.roomid = t.RoomId AND cu.date NOT BETWEEN '$from' and '$to' 
WHERE t.Start <= '$from' AND t.End >= '$from' ORDER BY USD
```

I want to get all the rows where the date is not in the cutoff table. But it is giving me the opposite! I do not know what to do, any help here would be greatly appreciated!

EIDT TO ADD TARIFA TABLE:

```
table: tarifas
RoomId      Start         End       USD       MXN
---------------------------------------------------
25        2012-11-01   2012-11-20   60.00    620.00
26        2012-11-01   2012-11-20   80.00    820.00
27        2012-11-01   2012-11-20   55.00    570.00
```

Comment: Post a sample of your `Tarifas` table please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (edited):

```
SELECT t.RoomId, t.USD, t.MXN, i.Image, a.RoomName, a.RoomDesc
FROM Tarifas AS t 
INNER JOIN Images AS i ON i.RoomId = t.RoomId
INNER JOIN Availability AS a ON a.RoomId = t.RoomId 
WHERE t.RoomID NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT roomid FROM cutoff
    WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to')
AND t.Start <= '$from' AND t.End >= '$from'
ORDER BY USD
```

Comment: this did not work... it still gives me back all results without excluding the room that has cutoff dates. Thanks for trying though

Comment: The first suggestion would return rooms without cutoff date or with _any_ cutoff date outside the selected date interval. The new suggestion using a subquery should work as intended.